# Update SharePoint List from excel

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have to update sharepoint 2013 list with data from excel sheets. Here, 2 excel sheets are being used. I need to update 2 columns of SharePoint list taking column A from one excel book and the other column from another excel book. My client doesn't allow visual studio coding. Is this possible? or atleast updating SharePoint list by taking only selective data (only 2 columns from entire data) from 1 excel book.

Comment: You can use CSOM/JSOM in a script Editor web part & to read excel & update SPList in your site.

Comment: Another approach is to use powershell for loading the excel spreadsheet contents into a variable ,then access site,spweb, SPList objects & insert the above spreadsheet contents-variable into the SPList  items. Ref.  https://podlisk.wordpress.com/2011/11/20/import-excel-spreadsheet-into-powershell/

Answer (score 2):

The ability to synchronize the data between a table and a list in Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services is deprecated.

for more info checkout msdn article [MSDN link here!](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462636(v=office.11).aspx)